# List.of gives a Compiliation error "The method of(char, char, char, char, char, char) is undefined for the type List"

Tags: java, list, oop, arraylist, collections

When i try and and run the the below code, the List(.of) does not compile and gives the subject error.

```
package collections;

import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class SetRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Character> characters = **List.of**('A', 'Z', 'A', 'B', 'Z', 'F');

        Set<Character> treeSet = new TreeSet<>(characters);
        System.out.println("TreeSet" + characters);

        Set<Character> linkedHashSet = new LinkedHashSet<>(characters);
        System.out.println("LinkedHashSet" + characters);
    }


}
```

Comment: It's only in Java 9+. Are you using a lower version of Java?

Comment: Yes, using 1.8..241.0

Comment: That version of Java is too old, List does not have those methods in Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

For older versions of Java, you can do

```
List<Character> characters = Arrays.asList(new Character[]{'A', 'Z', 'A', 'B', 'Z', 'F'});
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. I am using JAVA SE1.8 and JRE 1.8.0.241.  Also, i have the same issue for this line of code as well. List<Student> students = List.of(new Student(1, "Rajesh"),                  but, your change above is not working for it. any thoughts pls?

Comment: Just use `List<Character> characters = Arrays.asList('A', 'Z', 'A', 'B', 'Z', 'F');` not need to create an array, `new Character[]{...}`

Comment: Actually , i got it.. thanks anyway. List<Student> students = Arrays.asList((new Student(1, "Rajesh")),new Student(100, "Adam"),new Student(2, "Eve"));

Comment: @YCF_L It creates an array behind the scenes anyway. But it’s still preferable, I at least find it much nicer and easier to read.